# How to match perfectly the texture with the UV layout

Tags: krita

I'm trying to match the UV layout with the texture. I tried to play with the trasformation tools (move,rotate,scale),but they are not enough to place the texture exactly inside the UV layout. What's the solution here ? Can I do it in Krita ? Or with another graphic tool ? which one ?

[image: a]

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a difficult time matching UV coordinates if you don't have the UV info from the mesh you're working with.

3d software is necessary to export the mesh's UV info.

Here's how to do it with Maya:

1. Open UV texture editor
2. Select the mesh
3. in the UV editor go to, Polygons > UV Snapshot
4. Settings window will open. Set the dimensions, SizeX & SizeY to your texture file.

[image]

Sorry, I can only help with Maya workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Krita does it in theory, but in practice you cannot get even the edges to fit. That's because Krita hasn't directed warp mesh, you cannot help Krita in any way to know the new edge directions.

Affinity Photo has better warp mesh, it's control points have strength and direction handles. Adobe Illustrator's Envelope distort with a mesh has the same capablity. With them you quite easily warp the edges to fit.

[image]

But it can still be useless. Every point in your texture image must be placed to right place. I bet you do not want the eye appear as texture anywhere else than onto the 3D eye. If your 3D model happens to be smooth bumpless surface, the placement of course isn't critical.

You should know that even in case your model still is a featureless surface, you should have some markers for the wanted places of eyes, mouth, ears, nostrils etc... on your UV layout. Those places should be defined in 3D.

You seem to use a pre-made texture image. It surely has some data of the projection which is used when the image is made. I guess it's a cylinder projection. You should prepare your UV layout in the same projection. Otherwise your task is hopeless.

Comment: I hoped that Krita or any other tool have the projection paiting feature. With it I can pick the texture content and I can spread it over the UV layout. this can be done in every 3D program,like blender,substance painter etc. I thought that it was a good idea to have it also in a 2D painting program.

Comment: I'm talking about something like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fODto17By7o

Comment: @Marietto a 2D image can be spred over another 2D image in infinitely many ways. You must somehow input which point in image A corresponds a point in image B. And that must be defined for every point. Warping is a way to input that correspondence as a definitely simple rule - you place some points and edge directions and the warp effect smooths the intermediate areas.  A math transformation formula is another way. If  you expect automatic processing (=artificial intelligence) something like "both seem to be males; A= a skin, B=skinless body -  lets match them"  you probably expect too much.

Answer (score 0):

Texture needs to be painted to the UV map to be accurate - you'll need to either warp and distort till it fits or repaint it.

The UV map is the 2D graphic representation of wrapping the texture onto the 3D mesh - so it dominates - you don't alter it, you alter the texture - or repaint it.

Comment: this is how it should be done ? ---> https://imgur.com/xhfimx6

Comment: Sorry, but it's **super** hard to tell *anything* about how appropriate that is, as I can't see the wireframes on the UV, and I have no idea what the basemesh looks like.
Typically these days most folks paint textures in 3D painting apps rather than in 2D raster apps like Photoshop or Krita - whether that's live in your 3D tool like Blender or modo, or in a 3D painting specialty tool like Substance Painter or Mari (you technically can 3D paint in Photoshop, but it's less-than-optimal) to be sure it's going to look correct, and to use PBR layering in the context you'll render in.

Comment: how can I cut the rest of the picture out of the borders of the UV layout ? how to close the cage ?

Comment: As user287001 said in their excellent answer, it seems that the pre-done texture map you have is based on a cylindrical UV projection, whereas the UV you have in the background is likely a product of a UV unwrap. I have been trying to tell you in my answer and comments that the ***reason*** the typical workflow runs in ***one direction*** *from* 3D *to* UV *to* 2D texture-painting last is to perfectly match the texture to the UV projection. If you start with a painted texture, you'll need to match your UV unwrap to it as closely as you can in your 3D tool; if not, nothing will align in 3D.